# What is the proper way of using React Hooks in Gutenberg on frontend?

Tags: block-editor, react

I'm mostly interested in `useState`. It works fine in `edit.js`, but in `save.js` it just breaks and it throws the minified React error, see below:

[image]

I tried creating a separate `.jsx` component file but it throws the error when it encounters `useState()`. I tried importing it from both `"react"` and `"@wordpress/element"` packages.

The component looks like this, something basic:
[image]

Then I just imported it into `save.js` in my custom block:
[image]

The Gutenberg plugin is installed, version 15.2.0.

Comment: The `save` attribute is supposed to  take the block’s attributes and render static HTML that can be saved to the database. It doesn’t run on the front end and it shouldn’t contain any interactivity. If you want a React app on the front end you need a separate script on the front end that renders the app into that HTML.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks, do you have more information about how to achieve that?

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with WordPress, ultimately. You just need to run a React script on the front end the same way you would with any HTML page. Give the saved block HTML a class to identify it, find that element with JS and render your React app into it.

Comment: @JacobPeattie thanks, I got it working by following these steps, I didn't even have to do all of them https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/367847/230262. It sucks because I had to Google a lot to find a solution, couldn't find anything in documentations or on YouTube...